# multiple .on() functions not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So basically I want to after clicking button add div with contacts and after clicking any of contacts alert info. Its just to simulate Loading of contacts from xmpp server and after loading opening new tab for chat.
HTML:`<button>append</button>`

JQuery:

```
$("button").on("click", function(){
    $("body").append("<div id='kontakty'><ul><li id='test3-imserver-soc'><div class='roster-kontakt offline'><div class='roster-meno'>test3</div><div class='roster-jid'>test3@imserver.soc</div></div></li><li id='test-imserver-soc'><div class='roster-kontakt offline'><div class='roster-meno'>test</div><div class='roster-jid'>test@imserver.soc</div></div></li></ul></div>");
});
```

so far everything works fine and contacts are appended to body, but when i try to execute:

```
$("#kontakty").on("click", ".roster-kontakt", function(){
    var jid = $(this).find(".roster-jid").text();
    var meno = $(this).find(".roster-meno").text();
    alert(meno + "\n" + jid);
});
```

its not working, but if I try to execute 2nd function on contacts I want to append used as body of site (without appending) its working fine. Any idea why this happens?

Comment: Every time you click the button to create that glob of HTML, you'll be duplicating elements with the same ID. That's an issue as well. Use classes instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your second event to use body and not the id.

id="kontakty" doesn't exist yet when the event is created and therefore doesn't fire. Attach higher in the DOM to avoid this problem.

```
$("body").on("click", ".roster-kontakt", function(){
    var jid = $(this).find(".roster-jid").text();
    var meno = $(this).find(".roster-meno").text();
    alert(meno + "\n" + jid);
});
```

The second problem that you have is that when you click the "button" that the first event is bound to, you'll create the same batch of HTML with duplicate ID's. ID's have to be unique, so you'll need to use classes instead.

```
$("button").on("click", function(){
    $("body").append("<div class='kontakty'><ul><li class='test3-imserver-soc'><div class='roster-kontakt offline'><div class='roster-meno'>test3</div><div class='roster-jid'>test3@imserver.soc</div></div></li><li class='test-imserver-soc'><div class='roster-kontakt offline'><div class='roster-meno'>test</div><div class='roster-jid'>test@imserver.soc</div></div></li></ul></div>");
});
```

- Updated `<div id='kontakty'>` to `<div class='kontakty'>`
- Updated `<li id='test3-imserver-soc'>` to `<li class='test3-imserver-soc'>`
- Updated `<li id='test-imserver-soc'>` to `<li class='test-imserver-soc'>`

With the delegated event listener bound to the body, that code won't have to change.

Comment: Thanks for explanation, its working now. I will accept in 4 minutes.

Comment: I typically use document instead of button, but yeah body is the same thing essentially.

Comment: Updated the answer to solve another problem that you have. You are creating multiple elements with the same ID and the ID attribute on HTML elements must be unique.

Comment: @CoryDanielson Thanks. Yeah multiple elements with the same id would not be a good thing :)